# Return the biggest loss a client made from prices list

Tags: python, python-3.x, interview-questions

A hiring company gave me the following challenge:

> We want a function which accepts a very large list of prices (`pricesLst`) and returns the largest possible loss a client could have made with only a buy transaction followed by a sell transaction. The largest loss is calculated as `pricesLst[index2] - pricesLst[index1]` where `index1 < index2`. Please then write tests for this function to ensure it works as expected guarding against all edge cases you can think of.

I did implement my solution, but they told me that it was not good enough. Can someone please tell me what could the issue with my code, and how to improve it?

````
import unittest

# Return biggest loss a client made | Time complexity O(n)
def find_biggest_loss(prices_list):
    # Store biggest loss
    biggest_loss = 0
    # Verify data-type and buy/sell transaction pairs.
    if (type(prices_list) == list) and (len(prices_list)%2 == 0):
        for i in range(0,len(prices_list)-1,2):
            try:
                sell_trans, buy_trans = abs(prices_list[i+1]), abs(prices_list[i])
                # Check for loss
                if sell_trans < buy_trans:
                    new_loss = abs(sell_trans - buy_trans)
                    if biggest_loss < new_loss:
                        biggest_loss = new_loss
            except:
                raise TypeError("The list contains non-numerical values.")            
    else:
        raise TypeError("Non-supported data type! Please use a 'list' containing buy/sell transaction pairs.")
    
    return biggest_loss

class Test_find_biggest_loss(unittest.TestCase):
    # Non-supported parameter data-type
    def test_parameter_type(self):
        prices_list1, prices_list2, prices_list3 = 2, "prices", True
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
          find_biggest_loss(prices_list1) 
          find_biggest_loss(prices_list2) 
          find_biggest_loss(prices_list3) 

    # Missing value pairs
    def test_missing_pair_list(self):
        prices_list = [20,10,10,30,3,6,200,500,1]
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            find_biggest_loss(prices_list) 

    # Prices list with postive values
    def test_postive_values(self):
        prices_list = [60,5,30,10,6,0,500,200]
        self.assertEqual(find_biggest_loss(prices_list),300)
    
    # Prices list with negative values
    def test_negative_values(self):
        prices_list = [-21,-1,-10,-20,-30,-60,-200,-500]
        self.assertEqual(find_biggest_loss(prices_list), 20)

    # Empty prices list 
    def test_empty_or_zeros_list(self):
        prices_list1 = []
        prices_list2 = [0,0,0,0]
        self.assertEqual(find_biggest_loss(prices_list1), 0)
        self.assertEqual(find_biggest_loss(prices_list2), 0)

    # Prices list combination values
    def test_mixed_values(self):
        prices_list = [-300,240,200,-250,-30,-60, 50, 70, 200, 150, 0,0, 0,-0.1, 50, -30, 5.5,8.7]
        self.assertEqual(find_biggest_loss(prices_list), 60)

    # Prices list that has no client losses    
    def test_list_without_losses(self):
        prices_list = [20,20,30,170,500,700]
        prices_list = [200,5000,435,9000]
        self.assertEqual(find_biggest_loss(prices_list), 0)

    # Prices list that has non-numeric values
    def test_non_numerical_embedded_values(self):
        prices_list1 = [1,[2,3,4],5,7]
        prices_list2 = [1,"ten",55,False]
        prices_list3 = [{},{},{},{}]
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            find_biggest_loss(prices_list1)
            find_biggest_loss(prices_list2)
            find_biggest_loss(prices_list3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```
````

Comment: I think you misunderstood the problem. You don't get a list of buy/sell pairs, you get a list of daily (?) prices like [100, 237, 42, 93, 17, 140, 121] and you must return that buying at 237 and selling at 17 yields the biggest loss.

Comment: It was stated that each buy transaction is followed by a sell transaction. So, according to the list you provided. The client bought at 100 and sold at 237, making it a profit rather than a loss.

Comment: Your understanding is still incorrect. This question is about something like stock prices and the client buys, holds for some time, then sells. Your job is to find the worst possible investment, which in my example is to buy stock on day 2 when the price is $237 and then sell it again on day 5 when the price is $17. Note that "A buy followed by a sale" does not mean that the sale comes immediately afterwards. The client can hold the stock for a while before selling again. The question even says "index1 < index2", not "index1 = index2 - 1" as you interpret it.

Comment: How are you getting the idea that this is a daily or stock prices? And that the client can hold his investment for some time? You are making many assumptions!? I am not sure what you mean with  "The question even says "index1 < index2", not "index1 = index2 - 1" as you interpret it." I didn't say that. Nevertheless, the task literally states that "pricesLst[index2]-pricesLst[index1", so to my understanding they mean each sell transaction comes after a buy transaction as they literally also mentioned that "buy transaction followed by a sell transaction""

Comment: The question says "The largest loss is calculated as pricesLst[index2]-pricesLst[index1] where index1<index2". In my example, this happens with index1=2 and index2=5. Since 2<5, this is a valid solution. Your algorithm fails to produce that solution and instead suggests a smaller "biggest loss", which is simply the wrong answer.

Comment: If you want a naive but correct algorithm, calculate pricesLst[index2]-pricesLst[index1] for all combinations of index1 and index2 using nested loops, then throw away those results where index1>=index2 and then report the minimum (most negative result) of what remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have misinterpreted the question. Still, you've written code based on your interpretation of the problem, and we can still make review comments on that code to help you write better code in the future ...

## PEP 8

[PEP 8: The Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org/) enumerates many conventions Python programmers should follow to increase the readability of their code.  These include:

- use white space around binary operators
- use white space after commas
- don’t use underscores in class names

You violate these in a few places.  You should use one of the many lint checkers (pylint, pyflakes, ...) to help clean up your code.

## Exception Handling

Your code reads:

```py
    for i in range(...):
        try:
            process(...)
        except:
            raise TypeError("The list contains non-numerical values.")
```

There are a few problems with this.

### Bare Except

What kind of Exception are you catching?  It looks like you are intending on trapping cases where non-numerical input is given, but it will also catch the entire range of other exceptions, such as `NameError`, `IndexError`, `ValueError`, `ZeroDivisionError`, `KeyError`, and so on.

If you are intent on catching a `TypeError`, explicitly catch only that kind of exception using `except TypeError:`

### Loss of Exception Information

Not only are you capturing any and all exceptions, you are also forgetting all of the exception information.  If you have some other kind of a problem deeper inside the your code, and it raises an exception, you blindly report "The list contains non-numerical values" and destroy any hope of debugging information being available.

Capture the exception, and report or log the exact issue.  Or at the very least, pass the problem details on to the caller.

```py
    except TypeError as type_err:
        # Maybe print the problem
        print("Find biggest loss had this issue: " + type_err)

        # Maybe log it somewhere
        log.exception("Type error in find_biggest_loss")

        # Maybe pass it to the caller with raise-from
        raise TypeError("The list contains non-numeric values.") from type_error
```

### Efficiency

Inside your loop, you establish an exception handling context ... and then destroy it and loop back for the next data, recreating the exception handling context, only to again destroy it ad nauseam.

Switch the order:

```py
    try:
        for i in range(...):
            process(...)
    except TypeError as type_error:
        raise TypeError("The list contains non-numerical values.") from type_error
```

Now the try...except context is only created once, which should be more efficient.

### Define your own exception types

```py
class LengthError(Exception):
    pass

def find_biggest_loss(prices_list):
    if type(prices_list) != list:
        raise TypeError("Not a list")
    if len(prices_list) % 2 != 0:
        raise LengthError("List is of the incorrect length -- must be odd")
    ...
```

As a bonus, having the checks written in this fashion means the rest of the code doesn’t need as much indentation, thus improving readability.

### Duck Typing

The [Robustness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) states "be liberal in what you accept".

Does it have to be a `list`?  You could test `isinstance(prices_list, list)` allowing the `prices_list` to be a user-defined subtype of `list`.

Does it really have to be a `list`?  A `tuple` would be perfectly acceptable, so `isinstance(prices_list, (list, tuple))` would be better.  But is that enough?  A user might define their own indexable container which could work perfectly fine.

Just use the container given to you.  If it doesn't define `len(...)` or fails on `__getitem__`, then it fails and will raises an exception all by itself.

## Loop Like a Native

Ned Batchelder has recorded a [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnSu9hHGq5o) on looping in Python. In general, there are always better alternatives to using `for index in range(len(container))`.

In this particular case, you want to look at successive elements in `prices_list`.  The [`more_itertools` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) has a function exactly for this; it is called `grouper`.

Let's rewrite the function using it:

```py
from more_itertools import grouper

def find_biggest_loss(prices_list):
    return max((abs(buy) - abs(sell) for buy, sell in grouper(prices_list, 2)), default=0)
```

Is that a little too terse?  Ok, here it is expanded out a little:

```py
from more_itertools import grouper

def find_biggest_loss(prices_list):

    biggest_loss = 0

    for buy, sell in grouper(prices_list, 2):
        loss = abs(buy) - abs(sell)
        if loss > biggest_loss:
            biggest_lost = loss

    return biggest_loss
```

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks a lot. I couldn't ask for a better answer. Just one more thing, do you think that I misunderstood the question as Rainer P pointed out?

Comment: Did you misunderstand the question?  Maybe.  Do you have the question source?  Do you have a link to it?  The way you’ve quoted it, it seems to starts in mid sentence, so I think you haven’t posted the entire question text.  Without the definitive question text, I don’t feel comfortable with taking a concrete stance.  However, the question you’ve answered is definitely “easier” than Rainer’s interpretation, so I’m leaning towards a “yes, you have misunderstood.”

Comment: I did include the entier text as it was provided. Nevertheless, here is the task with its exact wording:
"We want a function which accepts a very large list of prices (pricesLst) and returns the
largest possible loss a client could have made with only a buy transaction followed by a sell
transaction. The largest loss is calculated as pricesLst[index2] - pricesLst[index1] where
index1 < index2.
Please then write tests for this function to ensure it works as expected guarding against all
edge cases you can think of."

Comment: 'Define your own exception types' - this is bad advice imo, you almost never need to.

Comment: @rak1507 Creating your own exception types is an important tool for your toolkit.  Like any tool, it can be overused.  In a hiring company's coding challenge, sneaking it into the code is a stealth advertisement that you know Python's exception hierarchy can be extended, so I would absolutely do it in this case.  It does open the door for additional interview questions, like what the parent class of the exception should be.  I used `Exception` above, but `ValueError` might be more appropriate.  It would certainly not be a `TypeError`, which the OP originally raised.